# Deque from a Thread withing a Process

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm after a little confusing problem. The thing is that I'm creating a Process using multiprocessing library and within that process I'm using a thread that shares a deque with the main thread. This thread captures frames from the picamera and stores it in the deque. The main thread just reads it and process. By the way, I know that deque works only within the same process so this is assumed cause I'm working within the same process on different threads. The thing is: when I'm not using process but starting a thread directly on the main process, everything works fine, but when I'm using a process, thing that I need thanks to the GIL, looks like I'm missing some frames. What is it happening? This is driving me crazy :P. Thank you!

Comment: It might be better if you shared your code. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).